# Using the SVG evenodd fill-rule in the canvas element

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

Does anyone know if it's possible, either natively or mathematically with JavaScript, to implement the `evenodd` `fill-rule` from SVG in the HTML5 canvas element? Links to projects that do this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible with [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing). If I'm not mistaken, default "source-over" value should correspond to SVG's "evenodd" (otherwise, try few others one and see if resulting image looks identical).

Comment: This works if you are drawing more than one shape. But if you are drawing a single path, it does not.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: composite != fill.  They are different concepts.  A global composite operation setting should not have any effect on fill rules

Answer (score 0):

By mathematically do you mean an algorithm implementation ? It is certainly possible, see http://gpolo.awardspace.info/fill/main.html. It is more a demo than anything, but it solves this issue "mathematically".

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same question and came across [this Mozilla Bugreport](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=655926).

Seems as it gets proposed to the WHATWG (canvas specs) by the bugreporters:

> Chris Jones, 2011-06-10:
>
> Let's wait for docs until this spec is looking solid on whatwg (I'll post today).

Answer (score 0):

That's a really old question, so things must have been different at the time, but since a long time ago, you can pass an `fillrule` parameter to the `fill()` method.
This `fillrule` can be either `"nonzero"`, the default, or `"evenodd"`.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
drawPath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.translate(70, 0);
drawPath();
ctx.fill('evenodd');
ctx.translate(70, 0);
drawPath();
ctx.stroke();

function drawPath(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(30,30,20,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.lineTo(60,60);
  ctx.lineTo(0,0);
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```